# Cross-referencing two parts of one JSON file in C#?

Tags: c#, json

Newbie question. I have a semi-complex JSON file that I have parsed in my program. The relevant parts are below:

```
{
    "version": "36",
    "released": "20220223",
    "samples": {
        "Samp1": [
            {
                "code": "A01",
                "status": "Optimal",
                "bestBy": "20210918",
                "expires": "20211018",
                "elementKeys": {
                    "H": [
                        "Hydrogen-std1-slt4"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "code": "A02",
                "status": "Optimal",
                "bestBy": "20211201",
                "expires": "20220501",
                "elementKeys": {
                    "H": [
                        "Hydrogen-std1-slt5"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "code": "A03",
                "status": "Optimal",
                "bestBy": "20230201",
                "expires": "20230801",
                "elementKeys": {
                    "H": [
                        "Hydrogen-std1-slt6"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "Samp2": [ ...
        "Samp3": [ ...
        "Samp4": [ ...
    },
    "element": {
        "Hydrogen-std1-slt4": {
            "format": "1.0",
            "position": 4,
            "standard": "std1",
            ...
            ...
}
```

What I need to do is populate some windows form controls with data from this file. However, thanks to the odd architecture, I'm a little frustrated over how to populate the controls for "code", "status", "bestBy", etc contained within the "samples" arrays (Samp1, 2, 3, and 4).

Only *some* of the samples are relevant and the relevancy is defined by whether or not the name of the element key is found further below in the JSON file. So, using the example above, within "element", the object "Hydrogen-std1-slt4" is found in the body of the JSON file with its own key-value pairs. I would like the program to see that and recognize that "Hydrogen-std1-slt4" is *also* found within the object in the "Samp1" array with the code "A01", the status of "Optimal", the best-by date of "20210918", and that it expires on "20211018". Since it isn't found in any other place in "Samp1", the program can ignore the other objects.

What would be the easiest, most logical way to go about making a conditional for that?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);

    string[] elementKeys = ((JObject)jsonParsed["element"]).Properties().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
    
    List<Samp> data= GetData(((JObject) jsonParsed["samples"]), elementKeys);

public List<Samp> GetData(JObject samples, string[] elementKeys)
{
    List<Samp> result = new List<Samp>();

    foreach (var element in samples.Properties())
        foreach (var item in element.Value)
            if ( item["elementKeys"]["H"]!=null
                && item["elementKeys"]["H"].ToObject<string[]>()
                        .Any(x => elementKeys.Contains(x)) )
                             result.Add(item.ToObject<Samp>());
    return result;
}
```

classes

```
public class Samp
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string bestBy { get; set; }
    public string expires { get; set; }
    public ElementKeys elementKeys { get; set; }
}

public class ElementKeys
{
    public List<string> H { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It feels like we're really close, but I get a System.NullReferenceException at if (item["elementKeys"]["H"].ToObject...
Do you think it might be because there are more ElementKeys arrays than just "H" and it throws an error when it can't find one of the other ones?

Comment: @a3dur4n I am always testing  and this code is working properly with a json you posted. You have to post the real json. This can be only if some elementsKeys don't contain H. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! It's true that elementKeys contain more values than just H. There's about a dozen elements with chemical symbols (Fe, He, Ni, etc...). I didn't want to clog up the question section with hundreds of lines. Still... your != null addition worked!